# getting correct address of char*

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to understand behavior of char* manipulation in C. 
Here is my driver code:

```
char *str1 = malloc(30);
char *str2 = "hello programmers.";
char *str4 = "and have a nice day.";
char *str5 = my_strcat(str2, str4);
my_strcpy(str1, str2);
```

and my implementation for strcpy:

```
void my_strcpy(char *dest, char *src){
  while ((*dest++ = *src++)); //dest value is at end of char*
}
```

1. when leaving my_strcpy, to my understanding, *dest* should point to the end of the string (because we kept incrementing it).

Now lets take a look at my strcat:

```
char* my_strcat(char *first, char *second){
  int l_first = strlen(first), l_second = strlen(second);
  char *tmp = malloc (l_first + l_second + 1);

  while ((*tmp++ = *first++));
  tmp--; // overwrite tmp's "\0"
  while ((*tmp++ = *second++)); // tmp value is end of char*
  tmp-=(l_first+l_second + 1); // rewinding pointer to string start.
  return tmp;
}
```

2. I had to manually "rewind" tmp in order for it to print properly outside the function.

**My question**, in short, is why do I get this behavior? I am not so sure how to describe my question, I hope it was clear enough. Why did I have to "rewind" my pointer in the second function, but not the first? Moreover, why didn't I had to "rewind" *src* and *dest* in the first function?

**Possible explanations I thought of:**

1. char* was passed by value to functions, and this is why I didnt had to rewind *src* and *dest* - proven wrong by debugger (checked addresses in and out of function scope).
2. in the first function, I'm passing as *dest* a pointer that was allocated outside the scope, whereas in the second function *tmp* was allocated inside the scope.

Thanks
(I was trying to provide as much info and attempted solutions like a good SO question should be, sorry if it came out too long)

Comment: You're not using the return value in case of `my_strcmp()` - how do you compare then?

Comment: `my_strcpy` gets copies of the pointers, you would need to pass a `char **` if you want to modify the pointer in the function.

Comment: *"proven wrong by debugger"* - how exactly did you check? `dest` doesn't exist outside of `my_strcpy`, it cannot have a value there anymore

Comment: C passes arguments *by value*, meaning the arguments in your functions are *copies*. Modifying a copy (like `dest++`) won't modify the original.

Comment: @SouravGhosh i don't follow - i am not doing any kind of comparison. did you perhaps misread my functions' names?

Comment: `dest` is a pointer that is passed to `my_strcpy()` by value.   Incrementing it within the function therefore does not affect the pointer passed.    Whatever is pointed to can be modified in a way visible to the caller, but the pointer itself that is passed cannot be.   Also, `my_strcpy(str2, str4)` gives undefined behaviour, since `str4` is longer than `str2`, and the function copies all of the data from `str4` to `str2` so runs past the end of the memory pointed to by `str2`.

Comment: @Colin I was trying to use the same prototype as the original strcpy, which (AFAIK) gets char*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why did I have to "rewind" my pointer in the second function, but not
>   the first? Moreover, why didn't I had to "rewind" src and dest in the
>   first function

It is because in `C` everything is pass-by-value.

1. When we pass-by-value we are passing a copy of the variable to a function.
2. When we pass-by-reference we are passing an alias of the variable to a function.
   It is copying the value of the pointer, the address, into the function.

Hence when you do `(*dest++ = *src++)` you are not incrementing the actual variables so your `str2` and  `str4` remains not effected.

In case of `char* my_strcat(char *first, char *second)` you are returning local pointer which is pointing to last character in the concatenated string hence you need to rewind.

If you don't want to rewind the pointer then just use one dummy pointer pointing to beginning of `tmp` and `return` the dummy pointer as below.

```
char* my_strcat(char *first, char *second){
  int l_first = strlen(first), l_second = strlen(second);
  char *tmp = malloc (l_first + l_second + 1);

  char *result = temp;

  while ((*tmp++ = *first++));
  tmp--; // overwrite tmp's "\0"
  while ((*tmp++ = *second++)); // tmp value is end of char*

  return result;
}
```

Comment: I have chosen this answer as correct because of the "no rewind" trick, also note _Some programmer dude_ and _Peter_ were saying the exact same thing and a bit earlier.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the dest pointer to be changed you need to pass the reference to it:

```
char* my_strcat(const char **dest, const char *source){
  size_t l_first = strlen(first), l_second = strlen(second);
  char *tmp = malloc (l_first + l_second + 1);
  char *result = temp;
  const char *tmpdest = *dest;

  if(tmp)
  {
      while ((*tmp++ = *tmpdest++));
      tmp--; // overwrite tmp's "\0"
      while ((*tmp++ = *second++)); // tmp value is end of char*
      *dest = result;
  }
  return result;
}
```